# click event of a button is triggered automatically when the dialog is opened

Tags: jquery-ui

In my project there is a form.

Whenever the enter key is pressed on any input fields, it submits the form. If anything goes wrong I display an error message in a dialog.

I use a function to initialize a dialog and destroys the dialog when it is closed. There is an OK button in my dialog that I bind with a click event when dialog is opened.

In IE as soon as the dialog is opened the click event automatically triggers and it closes the dialog. It only happens when a keypress event has occured from a input field with type = "text". With the select tag and button it works fine. I have tried using blur also, but only the click event is triggered automatically.

I am attaching the code below:

```
function showWeekEditBlocked() {
  $('#weekBlockedMessage').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    minHeight: 100,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    width: 350,
    stack: false,
    zIndex: 90,
    open: function(event, ui) {
      $('input#weekBlockedMessage_ok').bind('click',function() {
        $('div#weekBlockedMessage').dialog('close');
      });
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
      $('#weekBlockedMessage').dialog('destroy');
    }
  }).dialog('open');
}
```

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle with this behavior?

Comment: @j08691 This is it http://jsfiddle.net/SnFrn/1/

Comment: keypress event from select tag opens the dialog and it closes only when the OK button is click. Is there any method to mock that keypress event was triggered from select tag even if it was from input tag. Please help.